# GUI not updating when adding a call to an external EM simulation program

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, tkinter

The program runs fine (but not updating in the middle of the execution). In that case while simulation is running the window says not responding, and can not update till the end of the whole program. Till I add those lines was working properly.
Any clue? Next are the functions that even they are executed are not reflected in the parent window.
Thank you very much in advance

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkMessageBox import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import tkFont
import math
import time

#Global variables
global W1, W2, xf, dim, xc_target, N_iteration, error, sub, Wmax
global path_sol_mag, img_sol_mag, imagen_mag, path_sol_pha, imagen_pha, img_sol_pha, path_sol_legend, imagen_legend, img_sol_legend 


def Update_solution_window(fin):
    var_iterations.set(N_iteration)
    var_error.set(error)
    print xf[0]
    print xf[1]
    var_l1_final.set(xf[0])   
    var_l2_final.set(xf[1]) 
    if (fin==1):
        s3=Label(root, text='Final Layout (solution)',fg="red", font=helv14, width=15).grid(row=10, column=9, columnspan=4, sticky=W+E+N+S)
        Grafica()

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def refresh_window():
    print "Refresco"
    boton_default.grid_forget()
    boton_new.grid_forget()
    ##  Refreshing vector
    dim[2]=W1
    dim[3]=W2
    #Resize parent window
    root.geometry("1280x410+50+50") 
    ##  Refreshing root
    var_W1_in.set(W1)
    var_W2_in.set(W2)    
    fi_l1=Label(root, text='l1[mm]', font=helv12, width=6).grid(row=8, column=9, sticky=E)
    fi_l2=Label(root, text='l2[mm]', font=helv12, width=6).grid(row=8, column=11, sticky=E)
    var_l1_in.set(xf[0])   
    var_l2_in.set(xf[1])
    en_l1_in=Entry(root, textvariable=var_l1_in).grid(row=8, column=10, sticky=E)
    en_l2_in=Entry(root, textvariable=var_l2_in).grid(row=8, column=12, sticky=E)
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    s3=Label(root, text='Current Layout (solution)',fg="red", font=helv14, width=15).grid(row=10, column=9, columnspan=4, sticky=W+E+N+S)
    s4=Label(root, text='Iter. No.', font=helv12, width=7).grid(row=11, column=11, sticky=E)
    var_iterations.set(" ")
    s5=Label(root, text='Error[%]', font=helv12, width=7).grid(row=12, column=11, sticky=E)
    var_error.set(" ")
    en_iter=Entry(root, textvariable=var_iterations).grid(row=11, column=12, sticky=E)
    en_error=Entry(root, textvariable=var_error).grid(row=12, column=12, sticky=E)
    fo_w1=Label(root, text='W1[mm]', font=helv12, width=7).grid(row=13, column=9, sticky=E)
    var_W1_final.set(W1)
    en_W1_final=Entry(root, textvariable=var_W1_final).grid(row=13, column=10, sticky=W)
    fo_l2=Label(root, text='W2[mm]', font=helv12, width=7).grid(row=13, column=11, sticky=E)
    var_W2_final.set(W2)
    en_W2_final=Entry(root, textvariable=var_W2_final).grid(row=13, column=12, sticky=E)
    fo_l1=Label(root, text='l1[mm]', font=helv12, width=6).grid(row=14, column=9, sticky=E)
    var_l1_final.set(" ")
    en_l1_final=Entry(root, textvariable=var_l1_final).grid(row=14, column=10, sticky=W)
    fo_l2=Label(root, text='l2[mm]', font=helv12, width=6).grid(row=14, column=11, sticky=E)
    var_l2_final.set(" ")
    en_l2_final=Entry(root, textvariable=var_l2_final).grid(row=14, column=12, sticky=E)
    salir.grid_forget()
    salir.grid(row=15, rowspan=2, column=9, columnspan=4, sticky=W+E+N+S)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that you are interrupting the mainloop whilst running your simulation. If you want to do both at the same time, you may need to look into making your program multi threaded so that both the mainloop and your simulation can run concurrently.